# Python creating a 1D and 2D image

Tags: python, image, dimension

The code below was provided to us and it basically prints that image which is shown in the second function:

```
import sys



# CONSTANTS
MIN_ROW = 0
MAX_ROW = 9
MIN_COLUMN = 0
MAX_COLUMN = 9
WALL = "#"
BUILDING = "b"
BUSH = "u"
PLAYER = "@"
EMPTY = " "
STAIRS = "X"


def display (city):
   r = 0
   c = 0
   print("CITY LEVEL")
   for r in range (0, (MAX_ROW+1), 1):   #LOOPS1
      for c in range (0, (MAX_COLUMN+1), 1):
         sys.stdout.write(city[r][c])
      print()
   print()

def initialize ():
   r = 0
   c = 0
   city = []

   for r in range (0, (MAX_ROW+1), 1): #LOOP2
      city.append([])#appends an empty list to city
      for c in range (0, (MAX_COLUMN+1), 1):
       city[r].append(" ")
   #               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
   city  [0] =   ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"]
   city  [1] =   ["#","@"," "," "," "," "," "," ","u","#"]
   city  [2] =   ["#"," "," ","b","b"," "," "," ","X","#"]
   city  [3] =   ["#"," "," ","b","b"," "," "," "," ","#"]
   city  [4] =   ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","b","#"]
   city  [5] =   ["#","u"," ","u","u","u","u","u","u","#"]
   city  [6] =   ["#","b"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","#"]
   city  [7] =   ["#"," "," "," "," ","b"," ","b"," ","#"]
   city  [8] =   ["#"," "," "," ","b"," "," "," "," ","#"]
   city  [9] =   ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"]
   return city   


# MAIN
def main ():
     level = initialize ()
     display (level)





main ()
```

Now I am trying to reproduce this for a 1D picture but for some reason I am running into type errors for the sys.stdout.write() of the first function. It seems to be trying to print the entire list compared to just one character of it. Can anyone help me debug?. Also can someone please tell me what is going on in the loops in the above code labelled LOOPS1 AND LOOPS2

```
import sys


def display(track):
    c=0
    for c in range(0,20,1):
        sys.stdout.write(track[c])
    print()

def initialize():
    c=0
    track= []
    for c in range(0,20,1):
        track.append([])
        track[c].append(" ")
    track[0]= ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"]
    return track

level= initialize()
display(level)
```

If anything is unclear please let me know and I will fix it asap.

EDIT: CODE FOR MY PROGRAM:

```
import sys
import random


# CONSTANTS


PLAYER = "@"
EMPTY = " "


#Takes the information from the function initialize() and displays it. Outputs the fitness simulation.
def display (track):
    r = 0
    c = 0

    print("\nTRACK")
    for r in range (0, (4), 1):
        for c in range (0, (41), 1):
            sys.stdout.write(track[r][c])
        print()
    print()

def speedDisplay(speed):
    options=["(w)alk","(j)og","(r)un","(f)ast run"]
    for o in range(0,speed,1):
        print(options[o],"\n")




def inputs():#ioerror here?
    values= set("wWjJrRfFlLsSeE")
    while True:
        move=input("\nPlease select the speed you would like to travel at from the options listed:")
        for m in move:
            if m not in values:
                print("\nInadmissable entry, Please only use inputs valid in the options above.")
                break
        else:
            break
    if move=="w" or move=="W":
        usedEnergy=0#turn into random functions later
    elif move=="j" or move=="J":
        usedEnergy=1
    elif move=="r" or move=="R":
        usedEnergy=2
    elif move=="f" or move=="F":
        usedEnergy=5
    return usedEnergy

def remainingEnergy(energy,usedEnergy):
    energy= energy-usedEnergy
    print("\nRemaining Energy:",energy,"\n")
    return energy

def amountLeft(energy):
# enter ioexception error here somewhere?


    while True: 
        if energy <0 or energy >20:
            print("error")
        elif energy>=5:
            speed=4
        elif energy <5 and energy >=2:
            speed=3
        elif energy <2 and energy >=1:
            speed=2
        elif energy <1 and energy >=0:
            speed=1
        else:
            break

        return speed











# This function is used to initialize the game track that will later be displayed. 
def initialize ():
    r = 0
    c = 0
    track = []
    #Creates each row and column. A "for" loop initiates which creates and appends an empty list to the list "track". Then, taking the current row into consideration, the respective number of columns are created via the inner "for loop and a space is appended to the end of the current row. The loop re-initiates and the process is repeated for all 4 required rows. This results in 4 rows and 41 coloumns.
    for r in range (0, (4), 1):
    #appends an empty list to track
        track.append([])
        for c in range (0, (41), 1):
    #appends a space to the current row
            track[r].append(" ")
    # the actual rows and columns are created below.
    #               0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O   P   Q   R   S   T   U   V   W   X   Y
    track  [0] =   [" ","0"," ","1"," ","2"," ","3"," ","4"," ","5"," ","6"," ","7"," ","8"," ","9"," ","A"," ","B"," ","C"," ","D"," ","E"," ","F"," ","G"," ","H"," ","I"," ","J"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "]
    track  [1] =   [" ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," "]
    track  [2] =   ["|","@","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"," ","|"]
    track  [3] =   [" ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," ","-"," "]
    return track   






def move (sRow, sCol, dRow, dCol, track):
    EMPTY= " "
    PLAYER= "@"
    DIVIDER= "|"
    track[sRow][sCol] = EMPTY
    track[dRow][dCol] = PLAYER






# MAIN
def main ():
    track = initialize ()
    display (track)
    print("\n(w)alk\n\n(j)og\n\n(r)un\n\n(f)ast run")
    usedEnergy=inputs()
    energy=20
    energy=remainingEnergy(energy,usedEnergy)
    while energy<20:
        usedEnergy=inputs()
        speed= amountLeft(energy)
        speedDisplay(speed)
        energy=remainingEnergy(energy,usedEnergy)



main ()
```

Comment: Do you need one display function that can handle the 2D and 1D case? I can edit my answer to take that approach if needed.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see this until now. The 2D and 1D are completely separate cases. I am trying to create a 1D and attempting to use the above as a guideline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this works:

```
import sys

def display(track):
    c=0
    for c in range(0,20,1):
        sys.stdout.write(track[c])
    print()

def initialize():
    c=0
    track = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"]
    return track

level= initialize()
display(level)
```

Your problem was you had a mismatch in how you're handling `track`. In `initialize` you were creating it as a list of lists but in `display` you were accessing it as if it were just a list of characters. Making both a list of characters was simpler, making both a list of list of chars is more general (allows same function to be used for 1D and 2D case).

## What's going on in the first loop?

From `display` in your first code block:

```
for r in range (0, (MAX_ROW+1), 1):   #LOOPS1
     for c in range (0, (MAX_COLUMN+1), 1):
         sys.stdout.write(city[r][c])
     print()
 print()
```

R is a row index that varies from 0 to MAX_ROW, 0 - 9. C is a column index that varies from 0 to MAX_COLUMN, 0 - 9.

`sys.stdout.write(city[r][c])` writes out the current row and column of city (which has been set to a single character) without a newline.

You're code is probably Python 3 due to the print() statements. It would probably help if you mentioned or tagged that.

I'm running Python 2.7 so I'll use the old print syntax so I can test the the code I'm posting. You'll probably have to revert it back (add parens).

I would write this as:

```
def display (city):
   print("CITY LEVEL")
   for row in city:
      for c in row:
         print c,
      print
   print
```

In Python 2 a comma at the end of a print suppresses the newline.

## What's going on in the second loop?

From `initialize` in your first code block:

```
for r in range (0, (MAX_ROW+1), 1):
```

`r` will be 0 to MAX_ROW, 0-9

```
    city.append([])#appends an empty list to city
```

`city` is a list. This appends an empty list to city.

```
    for c in range (0, (MAX_COLUMN+1), 1):
```

`c` will b 0 to MAX_COLUMN, 0-9

```
        city[r].append(" ")
```

Append a space character to the current row.

I would write this as:

```
def initialize():
   city = [
       # 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
       ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"], # 0
       ["#","@"," "," "," "," "," "," ","u","#"], # 1
       ["#"," "," ","b","b"," "," "," ","X","#"], # 2
       ["#"," "," ","b","b"," "," "," "," ","#"], # 3
       ["#"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","b","#"], # 4
       ["#","u"," ","u","u","u","u","u","u","#"], # 5
       ["#","b"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","#"], # 6
       ["#"," "," "," "," ","b"," ","b"," ","#"], # 7
       ["#"," "," "," ","b"," "," "," "," ","#"], # 8
       ["#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#","#"], # 9
   ]
   return city
```

## about city.append([])

In `initialize` there is a line (in the first `for` loop):

```
city.append([])#appends an empty list to city
```

Before the loop is entered `city` is:

```
[]
```

Right after the first append `city` is:

```
[[]]
```

That is a list that contains one item, an empty list.

If the line were:

city.append(0)

It would be:

```
[0]
```

Or:

```
city.append("Jim")
```

It would give you:

```
["Jim"]
```

But we stick another list inside the list, creating a list of lists.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks however there is still some ambiguity. Firstly, I need the "for" statements, because the range will later change based on the value of a global constant. Secondly, what do you mean by list of lists? Where is that present and what does it output exactly?

Comment: Thanks for the edit you're awesome. Hoping to give you best answer once the post is done.

Comment: I have a question about city.append([]).    After this code is implemented will city now look like this: city= [] []? I ask because city initially had an empty list on it already? And if so, then what is being added to the first empty list in city= [] []? Would the "for" loop look at only the second empty list and work with that and so on for each continuous list, thus leaving the first list empty forever? @jimhark

Comment: @SajSeesSound, I need formatting to properly explain city.append([]). I'm writing and answer at the end of my answer above.

Comment: oooookay I understand it perfectly now. Looking outside of context.... if you had something like listvariable= [][], does this actually mean [  []  ], minus the spaces?

Comment: @SajSeesSound, I'm glad your getting it. Once you really understand it, you will not remember why it was ever difficult. 'listvariable= [][]' is a syntax error, but it's easy to see your confusion. Say, 'lv = [ [1,2], [8,9] ]', then 'lv[0]' is [1,2] and 'lv[1]' is [8,9]. So 'lv[0][0]' is 1, 'lv[0][1]' is 2, 'lv[1][0]' is 8, 'lv[1][1]' is 9.  lv is a list of lists. lv[i] selects element i from lv and returns a list. lv[i][j] goes further and gets element j from the contained list.

Comment: @SajSeesSound, what platform are you running: Windows, OS X, Linux? There are great environments available for Python development. Windows has PyScripter, and all major platforms support Python IDLE and PyDev for Eclipse. A nice dev environment or language shell can really help with learning Python. You enter Python code to see what happens. You play around a little bit, use dir() and help(). It can *really* accelerate learning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19883/discussion-between-sajseessound-and-jimhark)

Comment: ^...you should write a textbook or teach a class or something. Excellent explanations. Could you possibly join me in chat for a different somewhat related issue. @jimhark